# How do you specify local directory when using SAS EG for including a file?

Tags: linux, windows, sas

Hi We're using SAS EG V 7.13 HF1 (7.100.3.5419) (64-bit).

I'm running a script from a local Windows directory. I have a file called sas_pwd.sas I'm referencing in the command:

```
%include 'sas_pwd.sas';
```

However it's not being picked up by my SAS script.

I'm getting the following error message.

```
24         %include 'sas_pwd.sas';
WARNING: Physical file does not exist, /sasdata/work/sasuser/rolap/sas_pwd.sas.
ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file sas_pwd.sas.
```

Which is in my home directory for SAS.

So how can I either have the script point to the file on my local machine where it's in the directory say: c:\mydir\me

or how can I have the script find the file ion the Linux server where it's in say /home/rolap/?

If you can answer to both that'd be a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

If the file exists in your Linux home directory then reference it there.  Usually you can use `~` as an alias for your home directory.

```
%include '~/sas_pwd.sas';
```

Or you could hard code your home directory path.

```
%include '/home/rolap/sas_pwd.sas';
```

LInux will not have access to your PC unless you are running some type of fileserver on your PC and have mounted your disk onto the Linux machine.  But there are tasks available for Enterprise Guide that you can use to upload a file from your PC to your SAS server.

Comment: Actually that makes a lot of sense. Yup, I hard coded my Linux directory where my files were and sure enough, it picked them up. Thanks!

Comment: Also the logical follow up question would be - so does that mean if I have a SAS program on my PC that I'm calling using SAS EG, does that man I can't call another program also on the same local Windows drive from that first program on the Windows drive?

Comment: You need to load the program file into EG for it know where it is and submit it to the SAS server.  Once the program is running it is running on the SAS server, so it can only access files that can be seen by that server.